# Populate Drop Down List using jquery mobile from textbox

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a textbox whose id is other and I want to populate this textbox value into drop down list This is jquery I am using to populate... but this is not working.. And I am working with jquery mobile.. this script works fine with normal jquery but as soon as I works with jquery mobile it doesn't works... Any suggestion will be appreciated...!! I want to do like this:- http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/dynamic-combobox-listbox-dropdown-in-javascript.html

```
    <script>
        function addCombo() {
            var optName = $("#other").attr("value");
            $('#category').append("<option value='"+ optName + "'>" + optName  + "</option>");
            $("#other").attr("value", "");
   $('#category').selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    </script>
```

This is the code of drop down list

```
<td>Category</td>
                    <td><select class="size" id="category" name="category" width="30px">
                    <option width="30px" value="" selected="selected" >Select</option>
                    <option value="food">Food</option>
                        <option value="rent">Rent</option>
                        <option value="gas">Gas</option>
                        <option value="enter">Entertainment</option>
                        <option value="grocery">Grocery</option>
                        <option value="general">General</option>
                        <option value="other">Other</option></select></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>Other</td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="other" name="other"/></td>
                        <td><input type="button" data-role="button" value="Add" onclick="addCombo()"></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".add_button").click(function(){
        $("#-menu").append('<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-b" data-icon="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-theme="b" aria-selected="false"><div class="ui-btn-inner"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">'+$(".what_to_add").val()+'</a></div></div></li>')
    });
});
</script>
```

this works...it was because of the jquery mobile...if u dont want to pasre input's...set data-role="none"

Comment: @mc_fish  thanks a lot... u made my day... really appreciated :)... Can you just brief that out your code..So that I can understand properly..!!

Comment: the mobile library adapted some elements so that they are user friendly! what i did? just added into ul #-menu(that the jquery created) a li like the others...there can be a bug, u should append into both the "new" element #-menu and into .custom_values

Comment: @mc_fish The code is working fine.. Suppose we are adding hello into drop down list.. and then we open the drop down list to see hello, then hello is there but we are not able to select that hello..!! Any suggestions??

Comment: $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>") add it to the select and to the ul

Comment: @mc_fish so it should be like this, '<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".add_button").click(function(){
        $("#-menu").append('<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-btn-up-b" data-icon="false" role="option" tabindex="-1" data-theme="b" aria-selected="false"><div class="ui-btn-inner"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#" class="ui-link-inherit">'+$(".what_to_add").val()+'</a></div></div></li>')
  $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>")
    });
 });
</script>'

Comment: @mc_fish what should be the actual syntax and where I should add that line..!! Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="what_to_add">
    <input type="button" value="add" class="add_button">
    <select class="custom_select">
    </select>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".add_button").click(function(){
        $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>")
    });
});
</script>
```

ive just tried the code and it works!

Comment: @mc_fish So clear the confusion I have made a link on which I am working.. This is the link I am working on, in this it is not working.. let me know where I am doing wrong?? I have done the same way you told me..!! ( http://www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing1.html)

Comment: @mc_fish I think simple jquery is working fine.. but as soon as I am importing some jquery mobile plugins.. it stops working.. As I have to work with jquery mobile... I think that is the main reason it is not working bcoz of jquery mobile..!! Any help will be appreciated..!! Thanks...

Comment: its because EXPDB = window.openDatabase(shortName, version, displayName, maxSize); you have a error there...now 3 things: 1. do not use js for database usage...use php, java, asp whatever but dont js 2. if u need sql manipulation on the fly use ajax, 3. u have included jquery twice!

Comment: @mc_fish I have removed all the database part.. As we have to connect to database using jquery mobile itself. And Now I am more confused.. So I have made two different links. Currently I am working on this link (www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing1.html) and on this I want the textbox value to get into drop down list and in this it is not working properly as you can try by inserting..But on this link(www-rohan.sdsu.edu/~verma1/whitneyExpense/testing.html) the same code is working fine Value is getting inserted into drop down list what is the problem??bcoz of some jquery plugins?

Comment: duno but there's the error...install firebug if u intend to develop web apps ps. the error is in the comment above(remove and see if it works) edit: its because of the select modification...the path for appending is wrong

Comment: @mc_fish **the path for appending is wrong** if this is the case then why it is working in other link(testing.html).. There is something to be done with jquery mobile plugins..!!

Comment: jquery droplist plugin "replaced" the select with some of his own tags...if you're still having problems...i will help but try to solve them you're self that the way to learn:)

Comment: @mc_fish i am working on this from the past night and still was not able to figure it out.. I have tried several ways.. So that is why I was working with two links.. just to know where I am doing wrong.. your help will be appreciated..!!

Comment: what does the select manipulation, the drop list? i debuged the site...it does the job but doesn't reinit the droplist thats the problem...just need the name of the plugin

Comment: @mc_fish Yes the select part is the drop down list... which plugin you are talking about.. everything is there in the code itself..

Answer (score 0):

in jquery this would be something like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="what_to_add">
    <input type="button" value="add" class="add_button">
    <select class="custom_select">
    </select>
</div>

$(".add_button").click(function(){
    $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>")
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replyin... So script tag will be like this:-
'<SCRIPT language="javascript"> 
$(".add_button").click(function(){
    $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>")
});
 

</SCRIPT>'

Comment: no you need to include jquery(this was for jquery library) it keeps javascript "easy" i can only recommend it:)

Comment: I wasn't able to understand.. Can you just brief me out from my example given above.. That will be of great help to me...!!

Comment: http://jquery.com/ download the library there and add it to your page or link it from google ie. <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
then init the library something like <script>$(function(){ here goes the code from erlier
});</script>

Comment: not working this way also..  I tried this way...
'<script> 
$(".add_button").click(function(){
    $(".custom_select").append("<option>"+$(".what_to_add").val()+"</option>")
});
</script>'